# implement touchesBegan for UITextField

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

Can you catch TextField events when a Touch happens? So far I didn't see the Touch event get registered to TextField. For example,

```
    * (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

{
UITouch *touch = [event allTouches] anyObject;

if (touch view == TextFieldView) {
do somthing.....
}
```

This a dummy code what I want to implement is I want a method that get fired when user touches the text field  for some period. 
If yes than how???

Enlighten me on this.

Thnx in advance.

Comment: More code please.  Show relevant bits of the @implementation->@end for the class with the touchesBegan operator, and the lines of code that you think tell Cocoa you want your touchesBegan method to be called (eg creation of textfield?).  You might also want to read the FAQ on how to format all of the code as code on the screen nicely. Questions that are easier to read are easier to answer.

Comment: Sorry that's "touchesBegan method" not "operator".  And can anyone else give a definite yes or no on whether UITextField can be subclassed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested this by writing a subclass of UITextField subclass that captures touches.

```
@interface TouchTestTextField : UITextField {}
@end

#import "TouchTestTextField.h"
@implementation TouchTestTextField

-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    NSLog(@"touchesBegan");
    NSLog(@"touches=%@,event=%@",touches,event);
}

@end
```

It easily captures touches and shows the text field as the view of the touch.

Comment: I accept that but the situation here is that I have a textfields inside scrollview

Comment: Scrollviews are a problem. They trap touches to decide if they should scroll or not so they don't pass touches to subviews as other views do. I think the problem has been addressed on STO before. You should search on scrollview touches.

Answer (score 5):

Right-click on UITextField in the IB and link Touch Down event to required IBAction

Comment: what method will be called when the user remove touch from textfield

Answer (score 1):

You could try overriding [parentView hitTest:withEvent:] in the parent view and claim handling of touches for the textField on a per-touch basis when the app / UI is in the appropriate state.

I think all the touchesMoved/Cancelled/Ended events for that touch then go to the parent and not the textfield until the next touch.  But test it and see.

EDIT

Or simply setting userInteractionEnabled=NO when you want the parent to handle touches instead of the textfield and setting it to =YES when you want the TextField to handle touches.  See the Event Handling section of the iPhone Application Programming Guide.